# How to operate 10Gbit SFP+ module if driver doesn't support SFP+?

Tags: linux-kernel

### Abstract

I'm trying to get a 10GBASE-SR SFP+ module running. The MAC driver doesn't support I²C access to the registers, therefore I want to use PHY-less mode. On the other hand, the "fixed-link" mode supports only up to 1 Gbit. The "in-band-status" mode is said to not work with my setup. Thus I'm running out of options. I ask you if there are further options to get things running.

### About the hardware

My company built an access point containing an NXP QorIQ T1023 Soc. This SoC includes a MAC which is connected to an SFP+ cage. We use XFI for the connection between MAC and SFP+. In addition, the SFP+ module is connected to the SoC via I²C to access its registers.

### About the software

I am running OpenWRT with a Linux 4.14.137 kernel. There are patches on that kernel (mostly from the OpenWRT project, some by us).

### Details about the problem

For the MAC, I use the DPAA driver. This driver uses the kernels phylib (a.k.a. PHY Abstraction Layer) to access its PHY. However, phylib supports only MDIO-connected PHYs, not I²C connected devices. The kernel also provides phylink which can access I²C devices *and* MDIO devices (according to my understanding), but the DPAA driver does not support phylink. Therefore, the SFP+ Module will not work in a "normal" way with the DPAA driver.

Instead, I try to use PHY-less mode by adding the "fixed-link" keyword to my DTS file. However, I can only configure up to 1 Gbit, but I need 10 Gbit.

There is an "in-band-status" keyword for the DTS file, but I didn't fully understand what it does. An NXP supported told me that this will not work with XFI.

To summarize, I considered the following options:

- Operating SFP+ "normally", register access over I²C --> Not supported by MAC driver
- PHY-less operation with "fixed-link" --> does not support 10G
- PHY-less operation with "in-band-status" --> said to be no option, but I don't understand why

### What I tried so far

- Checked XFI link: I read the MACs registers, and it says the XFI link is up. I didn't find an equivalent register on the SFP+ side. The Ethernet switch (this is my link partner for the fiber link) says the link is up (LED is on).
- Reading SFP+ registers: I can actually read the registers of the SFP+ module. I tried that on the U-boot commandline, just to test the I²C connection.
- Hacking the phylib: I tried to add 10G mode to the "fixed-link" mode and had limited success. My MAC can now receive packets but not send. I believe that the MAC still thinks the link were down. I'm currently working in that area.

### My questions

- Is there a method to operate the SFP+ module which I'm unaware of?
- As a side question: Is there a good overview available over the MII connection types? I'm still unaware if XFI and SFI are the same, or how XFI and XGMII are related and so on.

Kind regards, Tanjeff

Comment: I am not familiar with the subject, so pardon for my questions: Do you write a driver? A linux patch? Because if the question is not about programming I am sorry to say it's offtopic here.

Comment: No, I'm not writing a driver. Actually I'm patching the kernel, but I'd prefer a solution which requires no kernel change. I think that my question is related to drivers and kernel infrastructure. If you have a proposal where to place the question, I will move it there.

Comment: I honestly don't know. It's a well written question, but I don't know where it fits. Have you tried the linux mailing lists? Or maybe https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ . I wouldn't delete it from here, maybe you get lucky and someone responds to you.

Comment: No, I haven't tried there yet, but I will :) Thank you for your advise.